# Writing a simple NSpredicate - Logic Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nspredicate

I have a `Person` object. and this `person` object has the following attributes;

```
Name
StartDate
EndDate
```

I am saving this `Person` objects to an `array`. This array might contain more than `100 person` objects.

The following is an example of `person` objects in that array;

```
John, Tue Feb 22, Thr Mar 30
Jack, Wed Mar 09, Fri Apr 21
Jack, Thu Mar 19, Fri Dec 20
Jack, Tue Jan 08, Fri Apr 26 etc..
```

Now i need to will supply a date, say for example `Wed 29 Mar`, and i need to check if it's in the range of `StartDate` and `EndDate` in the array of `persons` object. How can i do this ? My working are as follows, but it doesn't work (It gives incorrect results)

```
NSPredicate *datePred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"StartDate>= %@ && EndDate<= %@",givenDate,givenDate];
            resultArray = [arrayContainingAllPersonObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:datePred ];
```

I also tried the following method, but it too gives incorrect results (which was taken off a SO post);

```
NSPredicate *greaterThanPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"StartDate<= %@", providedDate"];
NSPredicate *lessThanPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"EndDate>= %@", ProvidedDate"];
NSPredicate *betweenPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:greaterThanPredicate, lessThanPredicate, nil]];
```

I have no clue as in what is causing this, Help

Comment: I have referred to the following guide when having to do calendrical calculations: [Apple Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html). The section on Calendrical calculations shows examples of how to determine if a given date is within a date range.

Comment: Could you tell me which example to read precisely?

Comment: Are `StartDate` and `EndDate` of `NSDate` type?

Comment: Also, sorry to point out the obvious, but you aren't actually using the same variable named "givenDate" twice in the formatted predicate, correct?

Comment: StartDate and EndDate are Strings. And yes, given date has to be given twice there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using '%@' like `StartDate = '%@' && EndDate ='%@'`

UPD:

Try

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"StartDate = '%@', startDateHere]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the StartDate and EndDate NSDate objects?

I'd suggest giving this writeup about predicates a look. It has helped me reduce my filtering and searching code to a few lines: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/03/filtering-fun-with-predicates/

Comment: StartDate and EndDate are both Strings.